# Select Option with first option from existing table entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that updates multiple fields in single table row. One of the fields needs to be a select / option box with the first option being the existing entry.

I've tried this:-

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
$repairRqd = "'.$row->repair_required.'";
//print out table contents and add id into an array and email into an array
echo '<tr>
<td class="hidden"><input name="id3[]" value='.$row->id.' type="hidden" readonly> </td>
<td align="center">'.$row->id.'</td>
<td align="center">'.$row->repaired_by.'</td>
 <td align="center">'.date("l",strtotime($row->received_date)).'</br>'.$row->received_date.'</td>
<td align="center"><input name="customer_name[]" value="'.$row->customer_name.'" maxlength = "50" size = "10"</td>
<td align="center"><input name="repair_required[]" value="'.$row->repair_required.'" maxlength="249" size="40"></td>
<td align="centre"><select name="status">
<option value="'.$row->status.'">'.$row->status.'</option>
<option value="Received">Received</option>
<option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
<option value="On Hold">On Hold</option>
<option value="Written Off">Written Off</option>
<option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
<option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
<option value="Collected">Collected</option>
</select></td>
</tr>';
```

With PHP of:-

```
//get data from form
$id3 = $_POST['id3'];
$repairRequired = $_POST['repair_required'];
$status1 = $_POST['status'];
$customerName = $_POST['customer_name'];

 // set queries for each item in the row
foreach ($id3 as $key => $value){
$query = "UPDATE repair SET repair_required = '$repairRequired[$key]' WHERE id = $value";
$query2 = "UPDATE repair SET status = '$status1[$key]' WHERE id = $value";
$query7 = "UPDATE repair SET customer_name = '$customerName[$key]' WHERE id = $value";
//execute query
mysql_query($query);
mysql_query($query2);
mysql_query($query7);
}
```

Curiously, I get the existing contents show up in the option list, however if I change it (by selecting another option) all that gets written to the database is the first letter of the selected option.

I've done a var_dump on both the POST['status'] and the variable $status1, and both are showing the complete text from the selection as I'd expect.

I can't see any reason why the complete string is not being written to the database and would be very grateful of any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the select  name as array

```
<select name="status[]">
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
$repairRqd = "'.$row->repair_required.'";
//print out table contents and add id into an array and email into an array
echo '<tr>
<td class="hidden"><input name="id3[]" value='.$row->id.' type="hidden" readonly> </td>
<td align="center">'.$row->id.'</td>
<td align="center">'.$row->repaired_by.'</td>
 <td align="center">'.date("l",strtotime($row->received_date)).'</br>'.$row->received_date.'</td>
<td align="center"><input name="customer_name[]" value="'.$row->customer_name.'" maxlength = "50" size = "10"</td>
<td align="center"><input name="repair_required[]" value="'.$row->repair_required.'" maxlength="249" size="40"></td>
<td align="centre"><select name="status[]">
<option value="'.$row->status.'">'.$row->status.'</option>
<option value="Received">Received</option>
<option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
<option value="On Hold">On Hold</option>
<option value="Written Off">Written Off</option>
<option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
<option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
<option value="Collected">Collected</option>
</select></td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: thank you. I couldn't see it for the life of me, but it is obvious now :)

Comment: I'm trying to but am unable to for five minutes for some reason. Will do so as soon as I'm allowed to by the system. - done now :)